# Propositional logic resolution program

Tags: prolog, resolution

I have to write a program which using *propositional logic resolution* can *decide 
if a  propositional formula is a logical rule or not*. The program takes as input some premises and one conclusion. The program should decide if the conclusion can be derived (deduced) from premises or not and *it should display
the intermediary steps* of resolutional proving.
**What is a good way(programming language, technique) to do this?** 
I've already tried to write it in *C++* but it seems to be more complicated 
than I expected.I also tried to figure it out in *prolog* but I don't really know how to display the intermediary steps.

Comment: Of iterest: [Types of Automated Theorem Provers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/869/268)

Comment: Of iterest: [Automated theorem proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving)

Comment: Of interest: [The World Championship for Automated Theorem Proving](http://tptp.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/CASC/)

Comment: Without any details or attempts and just seeking advice, this is not really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was on the fence about giving this a close vote, but now that others see it the same way I too have to give it a close vote as being too broad, or off topic, or for being a subjective question, e.g. use of  `best`

Comment: The first chapter of Blackburn & Bos 1999 is a very readable answer to this question - and more, of course